# Using f:validateRegex and p:inputMask together

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to make a regex check for my time input text and also I am trying to mask the input. I don't know if both can be done at the same time with this code:

```
<p:inputMask mask="99:99" size="5" maxlength="5" required="true" requiredMessage="#{account_req_txt}" value="#{user.accountNo}">
     <f:validateRegex pattern="[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]"/>
     <p:ajax event="blur" update="sysMsg" />
</p:inputMask>
```

I am getting "must be a number consisting of one or more digits." error. What is wrong with above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How exactly is the "account number" as represented by `#{user.accountNo}` a time? That part is confusing. In any way, the error suggests that the `accountNo` is *actually* a `Number` like `Integer`, `Long`, etc, not a `String`.

Perhaps you meant to bind it to `#{user.time}` or something else. At least, the value must be bound to a `String`, otherwise you need to create a `Converter` to convert between a `String` in `99:99` representation to a number type in `9999` representation.

Comment: Thanks again!  I chose binding the value to a String.